# drupal_add_js doesn't 'stick' outside of hook_js_alter and hook_page_alter

Tags: hooks, javascript

Putting together a module that needs to insert javascript into each based on the contents of the page being viewed. The following code block works fine in hook_js_alter and hook_age_alter:

```
$tracking_code = generate_base_code();
  if (isset($tracking_code)) {
    $javascript = drupal_add_js($tracking_code, array(
        'type'       => 'inline',
        'every_page' => TRUE,
        'group'      => JS_DEFAULT,
        'weight'     => 10,
      )
    );
dpm($tracking_code, 'INSERTED BASE TRACKING CODE');
```

The javascript in $tracking_code appears in the page source and fires off properly if this block is in hook_js_alter and hook_age_alter. If I move it to any other function, user-defined or something like hook_commerce_cart_product_add, it doesn't appear in the page source nor does it fire off at any point. If I add this to the end:

```
dpm($javascript, "JAVASCRIPT");
```

The debug output shows it in the array, but, again, it's not in the page source. Also, the $javascript array only has 8 or so elements (with the supposedly inserted javascript at the end) instead of the usual 30-40 element array that comes with a dpm() of the $javascript array inside hook_js_alter. What gives? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED:** Here's one piece of code in particular that I'm talking about:

```
function blargh_commerce_cart_product_add($order, $product, $quantity, $line_item) {
  $item = array(
    'id'       => $product->sku,
    'name'     => $product->title,
    'category' => $product->type,
    'price'    => $product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] / 100,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
  );
  // blargh_send_addremove($item, 'add');

  $tracking_code = blargh_generate_base_code();
  if (isset($tracking_code)) {
    $javascript = drupal_add_js($tracking_code, array(
        'type'       => 'inline',
        'group'      => JS_DEFAULT,
        'weight'     => 20,
      )
    );
    // dpm($tracking_code, 'INSERTED BASE TRACKING CODE (hook_commerce_cart_product_add)');
  }
  $code = <<<HTML
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': '{$item['id']}',
  'name': '{$item['name']}',
  'category': '{$item['category']}',
  'brand': '',
  'variant': '',
  'price': '{$item['price']}',
  'quantity': '{$item['quantity']}'
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
HTML;
  $javascript = drupal_add_js($code, array(
      'type'   => 'inline',
      'group'  => JS_DEFAULT,
      'weight' => 20,
    )
  );
  // dpm($code, 'INSERTED TRACKING CODE (hook_commerce_cart_product_add)');
  // dpm($javascript, "JAVASCRIPT (hook_commerce_cart_product_add)");
}
```

The code that follows the line

```
// blargh_send_addremove($item, 'add');
```

was originally the blargh_send_addremove() function.  In this case, when the dpm statements are uncommented, they all show the added $tracking_code and $code in $javascript, but when I look at the page source, neither is present.

Comment: Please put a whole code of your hooks. Also, remember that return value of your `drupal_add_js` is not updated. You didn't make `$javascript` global, so `$javascript` in hook and `$javascript` outside it are two totally unrelated variables - using same name for both of them may suggest it is one variable, but that's misleading.

Comment: I just updated the post with one example function that fires every time someone adds an item to a shopping cart.  I don't understand why I need to make $javascript global.  I'm not dpm'ing it's contents outside the block it's being assigned in.  Per the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), the return value for drupal_add_js is "[t]he current array of JavaScript files, settings, and in-line code, including Drupal defaults, anything previously added with calls to drupal_add_js(), and this function call's additions."

Comment: As regards hook_commerce_cart_product_add, bear in mind this may be fired in an AJAX callback or before redirection to another page. You cannot use drupal_add_js in this case. If there's a form on the page that is relevant, consider using the #attached property to load the JS instead.